# Is there an independent organisation that oversees the professional conduct of researchers in the UK/EU?

Tags: united-kingdom, research-misconduct, eu

By professional conduct, I refer to issues related to how a researcher manages his/her research group, including funding (both research and salary) and human resource issue.

For example, there is the Office of the Independent Adjudicator in the UK that reviews student complaints against higher-education providers. But the service offered is restricted to students, and not directly relevant to the professional conduct of a researcher.

An example of such an organisation in the financial field is the Financial Conduct Authority, who oversees the professional conduct of both organisations and individuals.

Comment: Well, there are more than one for these issues. However, they are totally different and change from state to state. For instance mismanage or public funding could be a criminal offense (in my state). One body that is internationally recognized and has power in *all* matters isn’t there AFAIK.

Comment: And overseer cannot be independent. Do you want something like a court of audit (largely independent but without direct power) or a state attorney/prosecutor? Manage complaints and special incidents or read everybodys files?

Comment: And for what it's worth: The university administration does exactly that: Check that profs don't go over budget and duely hand in reports, pay the actual bills and salaries, etc.